# Would this JS function be considered recursive?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, recursion

Not sure whether or not this function can be considered recursive.

```
var capitalizeWords = function(input) {
    var results = [];

    if(typeof input === 'string'){
            return input.toUpperCase();
    }else{
        input.forEach(function(word){
            results = results.concat(capitalizeWords(word));    
        });
    }
    return results;
};
```

//capitalizes all words in the array

Comment: Yes this is recursive...

Comment: Function that calles itself is recursive, by definition.

Comment: yes, as it calls itself. more info: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~calvin/cs110/RECURSION.html

Comment: Sure, any function that calls itself is considered a recursive function.

Comment: `input.join(',').toUpperCase().split(',')` without recursive

Comment: It is recursive but doesn't look like the recursiveness is required (see @The's comment)

Comment: @celerno recursion is never required - any recursive approach can be made iterative

Comment: @VallyN Surely you see it's not `captitalizeWords` that calls itself... It's indirect recursion.

Comment: @eh Depends on how you look at it. None of the control flow methods in JavaScript reflects what happens in a modern VM and in the underlying CPU surely doesn't really support functions at all. It's an illusion done with a stack and fancy goto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it's not direct recursion but indirect recursion.

The recursion doesn't happen in the actual function but in an anonymous higher order function.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, question turned out a bit more interesting that it looked first.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, is recursive function.

```
results = results.concat(capitalizeWords(word));
```